# Schedule task set as priority and must be run

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I created a schedule task and wanted it to be run everyday on time.
How to configure it to run priority？

Which should I tick for the settings below?
Start the task only if the computer is idle for
Stop if the computer ceases to be idle
restart if the idle state resumes

Power
Start the task only if the computer is on AC computer
Stop if the computer switches to battery power.

Wake the computer to run this task.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Neither setting you have checked will achieve this. Setting the tasks to run on a schedule is controlled by the Triggers tab.  That is where you can define the time and frequency for the task to be run (e.g. Daily at 10am)

Those conditions you referenced above define the conditions under which the task should be executed depending on the computers power and sleep state (the AC power usually only refers to laptops). Bear in mind that 'wake' will only affect sleep states and not hibernation or from a shutdown state. If you need the computer to auto-start you will have to look at BIOS settings for auto-booting or perhaps rely on an 'always-on' device that can issue a Wake On Lan command on a schedule (e.g. a router modem that can issue Wake On Lan on a schedule or using a cron daemon)